# How to isolate features in a multi-index array

Tags: python, multi-index

I want to isolate features in a multi index array.
This is what my array looks like

I have tried to search for spy

```
date,symbol,open,high,low,close,volume
2012-01-03,AAPL,58.49,58.93,58.43,58.8,75555200.0
2012-01-03,CSCO,18.55,18.86,18.48,18.63,41200000.0
2012-01-03,INTC,24.62,24.89,24.39,24.54,44800000.0
2012-01-03,MSFT,26.55,26.96,26.39,26.77,64700000.0
2012-01-03,SPY,127.76,128.38,127.43,127.5,194000000.0
2012-01-04,AAPL,58.57,59.24,58.47,59.1,65005500.0
2012-01-04,CSCO,18.44,19.0,18.35,18.99,52900000.0
2012-01-04,INTC,24.57,25.13,24.53,25.11,47500000.0
2012-01-04,MSFT,26.82,27.47,26.78,27.4,80500000.0
2012-01-04,SPY,127.2,127.81,126.71,127.7,127000000.0
```

- read the `DataFrame` in with:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
df.set_index(['date', 'symbol'], inplace=True)
```

How do I isolate the SPY symbol in the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Given the following `DataFrame`:

[image]

---

#### Without resetting the index:

```
df_spy = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('symbol') == 'SPY']
```

[image]

---

#### With resetting the index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_spy = df[df.symbol == 'SPY']
```

[image]